# How notify second thread of variable's change

Tags: java, multithreading, observable

I have two threads. The first changes the value of variable Data. And second one print the value if its value has changed. I am trying to do that second thread just print each time that the variable's value changed, but I don't reach success. Someone can help me?

thread 1

```
 class someservice{

     volatile int data;
     Boolean Flag = false;

     public void mymethod(){

         flag = true;

         for (Integer i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {

             data = someMethod();  //this method when called return a new 
                                   //value  
         }

         flag = false;
         ...
     }
  }
```

thread 2

```
 Promise p = task {
            try {

                while (true) {

                    if (engineService.getFlag()) {

                            print(someservice.data);                              

                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you setting `engineService.getFlag()` to `true` when you change the variable? I don't see it in your code...

Comment: you are on the right track... instead promise use callable, future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention Promises, I infer you are familiar with future/ promise in +**C++11**

in java there is a similar approach,  with future callable...

```
public class HW5 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    FutureTask<Boolean> myFutureTask = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        // implement the logic here and return true if everything was
        // ok, false otherwise.
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("dddd");
        return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0;
        }
    });

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executor.execute(myFutureTask);
    Boolean result = myFutureTask.get();
    System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

FutureTask in a class that takes a callable which can return an Object after its job is done... in Order to execute the Future task you can use a Executor service, especifically calling the method execute, since you need to wait for the thread to do the job then is necessary that you call **Future.get**, that will basically blocks the main thread until the future is done, to verify the result, just read the variable **result**..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the notify() and notifyAll() methods within thread.  Check out this link:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

```
public synchronized void guardedJoy() {
    // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
    // be the event we're waiting for.
    while(!joy) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}


public synchronized notifyJoy() {
    joy = true;
    notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Don’t write an empty catch block.  And don’t ignore an InterruptedException;  an interrupt is an explicit request from another thread to stop what you’re doing and exit gracefully.  Ignoring it makes your code a rogue thread.

Comment: Agreed.  That's a snippet from the Oracle link I referenced.  I don't think he/she would use the code verbatim.  :)

Comment: Thanks It was already solved by the previously answwer. Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

You have to look up more data about Concurrent programming,I can tell you now some basics,well,not so so basic,but i will do my best:

Here,you have a Monitor,it is an abstract concept,in resume,a Monitor is a
class with all it's
method using"syncronized"
as modifier, it means,
that only
one thread
can access
the method
at once.So,
in the
monitor is
the variable
that you
want to print,
and the"flag",
that tells you if
the variable
was modified.Finally,
you can
see the
most important thing,the"wait()"and"notify()"methods,
those method
stops the thread,or"play"
them again.

You ask
here in

the printValue() method, if your variable was changed, if the variable was'nt change, put the thead to sleep with the wait() method, and when the other

method changeValue() is executed, the value is modified, and the notify() method is called, waking up the thread, so, doing all this, you can guarantee three things:

Safety: meaning that the threads will do that you want
Absence of deadlock: meaning that the thread that is put to sleep, will be awake in the future.
Mutex: meaning that only one thread is executing the critical code, for example, the op. "++" is not atomic, is Subdivided inside in more the one action, create a local var, read the var, sum, and asign, so, if more than one thread are in the game, the value may not be consecutive, example:

```
i = 0;
i ++;
output: 1;
output: 2;
output: 3;
output: 5;
output: 4;
output: 7;
```

That could happen, and even so, that will happen in the next code, because there a more than one thread executing. Well, this is the way to program with several threads, more or less

```
    public class Monitor {

        private int value = 0;
        public static boolean valueHasChanged = false;

        public synchronized int changeValue(int newValue){
            this.value = newValue;
            Monitor.valueHasChanged = true;
            this.notify();
            return this.value + 1;
        }

        public synchronized void printValue(){
            while(!Monitor.valueHasChanged){
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(this.value);
            Monitor.valueHasChanged = false;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Monitor ac = new Monitor();

            BClass t1 = new BClass(ac);
            AClass t2 = new AClass(ac);

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
```

Now the threads:

```
    public class AClass extends Thread{

        private Monitor ac;

        public AClass(Monitor ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                this.ac.printValue();
            }
        }

    }
```

And finally:

```
    public class BClass extends Thread{

        private Monitor ac;

        public BClass(Monitor ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int v = 0;
            while(true){
                this.ac.changeValue(v);
                v++; // this sum is not secure, if you want to print an 
                     // ascending order, the code is diferent, I will show in
                     // above.
            }
        }
```

Now, if you want an ordered print:

the monitor will look like:

```
    public class Monitor {

        private int value = 0;
        public boolean valueHasChanged = false;
        private boolean hasPrint = true;

        public synchronized void changeValue(int newValue) {
            this.value = newValue;
            this.valueHasChanged = true;
            this.notify();
        }

        public synchronized void changeValuePlusOne() {
            while (!hasPrint) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            this.value++;
            this.valueHasChanged = true;
            this.hasPrint = false;
            this.notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void printValue() {
            while (!this.valueHasChanged) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(this.value);

            this.valueHasChanged = false;
            this.hasPrint = true;
            this.notifyAll();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Monitor ac = new Monitor();

            BClass t1 = new BClass(ac);
            AClass t2 = new AClass(ac);

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

    }
```

And the Threads:

```
    public class BClass extends Thread{

        private Monitor ac;

        public BClass(Monitor ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                this.ac.changeValuePlusOne();
            }
        }

        }
```

The other Thread look equals:

```
public class AClass extends Thread{

    private Monitor ac;

    public AClass(Monitor ac) {
        this.ac = ac;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            this.ac.printValue();
        }
    }

}
```